# WhatsApp intercept Profile photo upload

Tags: android, http, ssl, xmpp, whatsapp

I've a rooted android device which runs on Android 5. I've WhatsApp installed on the device.

Now, the aim.

I want to update the WhatsApp profile photo with out opening the WhatsApp official application. Is it possible ? If yes, where should i start ? What will be the steps ?

I got little bit knowledge of Java and android application development. Once i get the method to update the profile photo, i could be able to develop a small app that will change the whatsapp profile photo in a specific interval.

I tried to analyze the network requests using `tcpdump` but i couldn't identify what's going when i update the profile photo using the official WhatsApp app.

If you need more clarification, ask me in the comments.

Thank you.

Comment: mate you are looking at decompilation, then try to make sense of that decompiled code, and writing an xposed module to achieve your purpose, and by the time you are done with the above 3 WhatsApp might release a new version in which they change this very functionality of the app, rendering you efforts futile, but you may try anyways.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. See [**Where to Start**](//meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6367/143094).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to update the WhatsApp profile photo with out opening the
>   WhatsApp official application. Is it possible ? If yes, where should i
>   start ? What will be the steps ?

You essentially wants your app to edit/modify the content of `WhatsApp` and that too a user profile pic, that is considered as private user information inside another app, in this case `WhatsApp`

`WhatsApp` did not release their SDK for Android and also did not made their APIs public to allow other 3rd party developers(like you and me and many others) to access the content of `WhatsApp`.

All `WhatsApp` allow is simple [`Intent`-based communication](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) from any 3rd app. For example, below is the simple code for sending text using WhatsApp

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

That's it.

There is no other "official" way to access WhatsApp, as of this writing, for 3rd party app developers.

Hence, unless you are willing to do lot of reverse engineering and non-official coding to get access to what you want inside another app who did not disclosed its SDK/APIs, this is quite tough.

Comment: first of all thanks for the response :).I knew there wouldn't be any official method to update the propic from a 3rd party application. but  As i told you, I've a rooted device so am searching for methods that can be achieved through `root` access to update the `WhatsApp` propic.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the profile which most probably would be in the database which is actually encrypted. So first you need to find a way to crack that encryption and do the changes and then encrypt it the way they do. In short Mission Impossible. But nothing is impossible, good luck ;)

Comment: Or you might need to consider doing automated task, make a program that can open whatsapp, click option menu, select profile,.. browse image ... select image from image browser.. click save... similar pattern. The idea is, automate user interaction with proper timing, because it may fail if not at right time.